# Strict prohibition on overlapping data. Why?

Tags: publications, data, publishability

The journal *Immunity* says on this [webpage](http://www.cell.com/immunity/authors)

"As a matter of publishing ethics, we cannot consider any paper that contains data that have been published or submitted for publication elsewhere."

Why not? What if the two papers analyze rich sources of data that overlap only partially? What if they have completely different ambitions? Is the only meritorious activity in science the act of gathering data, and to hell with the analysis? And what does this have to do with ethics?

Comment: It _might_ be related to the idea that published data is the intellectual property of the publisher, such that publishing it elsewhere infringes upon the original publisher's property rights.  Presumably if _Immunity_ wants to be able to sue others for publishing data that first appeared in _Immunity_, they'd have to ensure that they similarly don't reproduce others' content.  (Not an answer since this is speculation.)

Comment: Thank you for your perspective. I suppose that concern is vaguely ethical in nature (ha ha, nature), although it seems ethically problematic to claim ownership of data generated at publicly funded institutions, by state employees, using taxpayer money.

Comment: So you're suggesting this grants them ... immunity ... from copyright accusations?

Comment: I think it's also weird the way they use the word "contains". The paper doesn't "contain" my lab's data -- it analyzes them. No amount of squeezing and centrifuging, literal or metaphorical, will allow you to recover the data from the paper. Am I in the clear, then?

Comment: For some types of data, like gels, the paper does literally "contain" the data. Maybe the guidelines were written in that paradigm.

Comment: Yeah, you can probably infer their position from the [Permissions section](http://www.cell.com/immunity/authors#permissions) of that webpage.  I think that their concern is that, if you publish with them, then their unique value proposition as a business is that they're a unique source of that information.  If you then just post all of that same data and writing (or/and an updated/expanded version of it) to another corner of the web, then they're no longer a unique source of it.  And if people start doing that regularly, then their ability to demand high subscription fees is diminished.

Comment: Ah, here we go: ["Rights, Sharing, and Embargo Policies"](http://www.cell.com/rights-sharing-embargoes).  They list that there's an "_embargo period_"; looks like the author isn't allowed to publicly share their article until after 12 months after _Immunity_ first publishes it, then they're only allowed to share it on non-commercial platforms.  And apparently this 12-month delay can be waived for a $5,000 fee (if I'm reading that correctly).  Anyway, they probably object to republishing data for the same reason as they object to republishing the article.

Comment: They don't object to republishing data -- in fact, they require most data be made publicly available at no cost via repositories such as GEO. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Is the data published in those repositories particularly useful to someone who can't read the corresponding article?

Comment: Yes, and especially if this hypothetical reuser could read the preprint. Anyway, you argue that this restriction is driven by a profit motive. They call it an ethical concern. What's the connection there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68723/discussion-between-eric-kernfeld-and-nat).

Comment: It is unethical to use the same control data for two different experiments without disclosing it, because it lowers the statistical power of the experiments.  This could be an additional factor.

Comment: @Nat That embargo period is quite common in biomedical journals, as it automatically complies with NIH requirements.

Comment: @Fomite Definitely; journals in general don't like authors making their pay-wall'd content available elsewhere.  Not even just scientific journals, but news outlets, too.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist : "without disclosing it". So what? Generally if you use data published elsewhere, as is often done, you cite the paper in which it was published elsewhere. But the bizarre policy appears to forbid that.

Comment: It has nothing to do with "copyright" it's to prevent salami papers, double submissions, and weak stats.

Comment: @Nat The pure data is nobodys property but the original authors, and since it is published, everybody is free to use it, as long as he gives the proper reference.

Answer (score 6):

I think you're reading a little bit more into the policy than is actually there - many papers in this type of journal essentially contains data - gels, lab results, etc. That's what they're talking about. What they're *not* talking about is the corpus of data generated from a whole study.

> Why not?

Because the goal is not to allow researchers to publish repeated analyses of the same dataset.

> What if the two papers analyze rich sources of data that overlap only
>   partially?

It's likely not what they're talking about - a rich source of data likely means that the data *hasn't* been published recently. What they don't want is "The same data as last time, now with a marginally different story".

> What if they have completely different ambitions?

I'd be impressed if you managed to get two completely distinct analyses out of the same data - and indeed, the stance of the journal would likely be that they'd be willing to accept a decrease in salami slicing of papers at the cost of the occasional genuinely novel analysis that's built entirely off previously published data.

> Is the only meritorious activity in science the act of gathering data,
>   and to hell with the analysis?

That's reading *way* too far into the policy - the paper should *also* contain that analysis. What they don't want you doing is writing four papers on the same single assay or whatever.

> And what does this have to do with ethics?

The idea that a paper should represent a single, stand-alone contribution to science, and that ever more esoteric spins on the same data is a net negative is an ethics in science stance. One you may disagree with, but it is one.

Comment: You'd be _impressed_ if someone can get two different analyses out of the same data set??? Why?? That is commonplace. Even if there was no disagreement about methods of analysis, there might be entirely different research questions.

Comment: @MichaelHardy In my experience for journals like the one in question, "data" comes from a single experiment.

Comment: So what? How does coming from a single experiment mean that you cannot get two or more different analyses?

Comment: @MichaelHardy It's my experience that that isn't how the immunology-related projects I have interacted with have been run. "We ran a particular assay/gel/etc. to answer THING. Here is a picture. Maybe a graph and a t-test." Generally speaking, an additional analyses involves pulling in and/or generating some form of *new* data, which, in my answer, would I think be allowable under the stated rules.

Comment: I tried doing a lot of fact-checking on their policies and claims.  To me it looks like this is about the money; for example, they have a portal that allows parts of publications to be reprinted elsewhere for a fee.  This seems inconsistent with the claims in this answer; would you happen to have references for them?

Comment: Just to note it, I think that responsible data analysis and avoiding common analysis mistakes is a worthy objective.  Just, these polices look designed to ensure exclusivity rather than analytical integrity.  For example, if a policy intended to prevent the same data from being considered multiple times (which itself would be based on a fallacious premise, as the literature can't be considered a fair sampling of results to begin with), it seems like it'd be adequate to explicitly declare that the data was published before to avoid confusion, rather than strictly prohibit it.

Comment: @Fomite : But generally speaking, an additional analysis, either addressing a different research question or disagreeing with the original analysis, does NOT necessarily involve generating new data. That's why there are famous data sets about which many papers have been published.

Comment: @Nat That's likely about re-prints for inserts by pharma companies. I get dozens of them at certain conferences.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I am not saying *all data sets universally* - I'm saying that *in the field for this journal* it's my experience that there's a 1:1 mapping of "Data" and "Research Question" more often than not.

Comment: @Nat As mentioned above, most of their embargo period can be explained as "We abide by the NIH guidelines, which will cover most of the papers in this journal, and if you want it to appear faster, we offer an open access option."

Comment: @Fomite Also, they say that it's okay to reprint parts of it, just not during the embargo period, and not in a commercial venue after it (though non-commercial venues are fine).  Surely that's a purely commercial policy, right?

Comment: @Nat That's likely "You'll have to put your stuff on Pubmed Commons anyway, so knock yourself out."

Comment: @Nat Nearly all of their reprint stuff can be explained by "95% of you are NIH funded, and the other 5% are possibly the kind of thing that pharma companies are going to want glossy inserts of."

Comment: How's the NIH related?  The publisher's website said that the embargo period was about maintaining subscribers, and they'll waive it for a fee.  I didn't see mention of NIH guidelines, and wouldn't waiving the embargo period violate any guidelines that required it?

Comment: @Nat The embargo period *conspicuously* adheres to the NIH's timeline for when work funded by them must be made open access (you can do earlier, hence the faster fee). This is them talking a good game about their compromise. It's identical to the language used by publishers I've been in meetings with.

Comment: If the NIH's timeline requires them going open access within a certain period, then it seems more like they're maximizing the embargo period within the limits of what the NIH allows, rather than doing it for the NIH, right?

Comment: @Nat Basically, the embargo period that's been laid out in this journal (and most medical journals that aren't for-pay Open Access is the same - there's no incentive for them *not* to go out to the maximum allowable window. But this was a compromise arrived at between the major publishers and the NIH to make work more accessible without detonating the publishing industry.

Comment: This answer makes a lot of sense to me, but I am not convinced of your reading of the policy. They're in the business of editing, so I assume they choose their words carefully. If they wanted to disallow something that's essentially the same dataset as published elsewhere, they could have said that. Instead, they wrote a policy that could cover any intersection, no matter how minor.

Comment: @eric_kernfeld There are all kinds of people in publishing who are not editors and likely had a hand in things. It's also a far more compact expression - trying to lay out express thresholds is *begging* for someone rules-lawyering around things. Easier to have a blanket policy for most of the problem and pre-sub inquiries for the edge cases.

Comment: Good reply. +1.

Comment: @fomite You’d be impressed by someone writing multiple papers from the same dataset? I’m guessing your field isn’t anything related to machine learning, because that seems to happen fairly often there - the dataset that you use to train the machine learning system is itself a variable, so if you want consistent reproducible results you’d need to use the same dataset to control that variable.

Comment: @nick012000 This answer is rather focused on the specific journal - and thus field - the questioner asked about. Which you'll note has been addressed in a number of comments.

Answer (score 6):

This is a guess but:

The sentence in question comes at the end of the paragraph entitled 'Related Manuscripts', which says they need to see any similar papers you have. This suggests to me that the primary point is that you can't publish the 'same' paper twice, even if you change the wording.

Another potentially relevant point, which I haven't seen mentioned yet, is that you have to be very careful when reusing a dataset - the more questions you ask about some data, the more likely you are to get a positive answer by chance, so that has to be taken into consideration in the analysis. If you present a single result from the data, it's therefore important to know what other questions have been asked.

Comment: I like your first guess, but I don't think this policy has anything to to with p-hacking, because if it did, there would be a lot more to say on that topic, and they don't mention it anywhere else.

Comment: Also, the policy as written covers a lot more than just the same paper twice. It applies to any intersecting data at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think the keyword here is "contains". The paper should not present any data, that has already been presented elsewhere, because that would be considered double publication of the data.

I'm pretty sure that this is not meant as a restriction on using previously published dataset in your papers. For example, I don't think *Immunity* would want to restrict papers from using data from the *Human Genome Project* or public census data.

(Am not sure how this is supposed to work with significant extensions of previous datasets though.)

Answer (score 0):

You must only write one paper in which you explain completely *how* you acquired the data and *why exactly* you did it the way you did.

The full story. A later paper which reveals that there were some additional motives, not to say parameters, turns the original one into a piece of scientific malpractice, eligible for retraction.

Comment: is "eligible" the right word?

Comment: Not wrong per se but you could choose another. I might say "subject to retraction" which carries a clear negative connotation; "eligible" is usually used in positive contexts. I disagree with your answer, though; there isn't a problem with a later paper that builds on or corrects a prior one, the problem addressed in the prohibition from the OP is representing work as if it is new when it is actually not new and has been published before. If that isn't clear, it's the later paper that is a problem, not the former.

Comment: @BryanKrause You can of course *build on* or *correct* an earlier paper. You seem to not have grasped the dire scientific problem with hiding relevant measurement parameters however.